# Django - template build-in filter tags {% url %}

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I am a new coder with Django. So, first apologize for it if this question is too easy.

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def save_comments_into_database(topic, user_id, content):
    data = Comment(topic=topic, commenter_id=user_id, content=content)
    data.save()
```

this is the code for form

```
<form action = "{% url 'post:comment' the_topic=topic user_id=1 %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to use url tag to call a function is views.py.
topic is a variable I passed in when this page is created.

this is my code in urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.comment, name="comment"),
```

then this is how I do in views.py

```
def comment(request, the_topic, user_id):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            args = {'form': form, 'text': text, 'topic': the_topic}
            # save the data in database
            save_comments_into_database(the_topic.id, user_id, text)
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return render(request, 'post/detail.html', args)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'post/detail.html', {'form': form, 'topic': the_topic})
```

I get the NoReserveMatchException:
[image]

I really don't get where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your `comment` URL only has one var, the `topic_id`, but you passed two vars, `the_topic` and `user_id`. You need to pass just the topic ID. Also, in views you would normally access the current user via `request.user`.

Comment: Hi Wyatt, I tried your solution, but I didn't get a pop up ".user" from request in comment function. How can i do that? @Wyatt

Comment: Please share your CommentForm() class as well.

Comment: @misraX Hi, it is solved, I forget to sign it as complete. Well, I still show the form if you want to check it.

Comment: Hi @Wyatt, if you like, you can answer this question again and I set your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment URL only has one var, the `topic_id`, but you passed two vars, `the_topic` and `user_id`. You need to pass just the topic ID. Also, in views you would normally access the current user via `request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

you should to change declare the urls, added second parameter and change name of the first

```
url(r'^(?P<the_topic>[0-9]+)/comment/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.comment, name="comment"),
#          ^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^
```

Comment: hi Bear, I tried it, it still gives me the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to serve the action redirection using Django built in `HttpResponseRedirect` in the views.py  and combine it with `reverse` of your url [Django docs ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), check bellow and change yourapp_path with your app path and name_space with url name like "blog".

### main urls.py with "name_space"

like namepsace="blog"

```
url(r'^', include('yourapp_path.urls', namespace='name_space))
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

### app urls.py with name="name"

like name="comment"

```
url(r'^(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.comment, name="name")
#                                                           ^^^^^^
```

### `reverse` with name_space:name

will return the complete path of the url taking `name_space:name` lets say `blog:comment`

```
reverse('name_space:name')
```

### reverse with kwargs or args

```
reverse('name_space:name', kwargs={'kw1': 'val1'})
reverse('name_space:name', args=['val1'])
```

### HttpResponseRedirect()

302 redirect to a given url in that case we will pass the `reverse` url.
like: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:comment', kwargs={'topic_id': topic.id}))

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('name_space:name', kwargs={'kw1': 'val1'}))
```

## views.py

```
#import HttpResoneRedircet and reverse
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, reverse
def comment(request, the_topic, user_id):
        # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
            # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                # your is_valid()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('name_space:name', kwargs={'the_topic': the_topic.id}))
```

### template

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you! Though the other guy already gave the answer, I still appreciate your answer!!